Why is turbo not available in my workflow, even though I install it?
When I try to run turbo run lint, I get a message "turbo: command not found". It seems that the dev dependency was not installed correctly in the previous step.
Here's the log output:

This is my workflow:
name: ESLint and Build

on:
  push:
    branches: [master, devo]
  pull_request:
    branches: [master, devo]

jobs:
  lint-and-build:
    timeout-minutes: 15
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Check out code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          fetch-depth: 2

      - name: Setup Node.js environment
        uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          node-version: 20
          cache: "npm"

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm install

      - name: Lint
        run: turbo run lint

      - name: Build
        run: npm run build

And here is the package that is responsible for installing the dependencies, among them the turbo pack, which in theory should installed before running turbo run lint:
{
  "name": "mundo-raro",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "workspaces": [
    "apps/*",
    "packages/config/*",
    "packages/shared/*"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "turbo dev",
    "storybook": "storybook dev -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "storybook build",
    "build": "turbo run build",
    "test": "turbo run test"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@chromatic-com/storybook": "^1.3.3",
    "@playwright/test": "^1.43.1",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^8.0.8",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^8.0.8",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^8.0.8",
    "@storybook/addon-onboarding": "^8.0.8",
    "@storybook/blocks": "^8.0.8",
    "@storybook/nextjs": "^8.0.8",
    "@storybook/react": "^8.0.8",
    "@storybook/test": "^8.0.8",
    "@types/node": "^20.12.7",
    "storybook": "^8.0.8",
    "turbo": "^1.13.0"
  }
}


Can you share the yml config and the package.json please ? Also you should use npm ci in this case : https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-ci

What makes you think turbo would be installed globally from what you've posted?

Try adding npx before the turbo command, also you should use the command npm ci.
On you computer, first run npm install in order to generate the lockfile named package-lock.json. Commit it and run npm ci in your GitHub Actions workflow.
Documentation : https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-ci

npm install does install the dependencies; ci is probably better in CI, but it's not going to change much.

You're right, I thought npm I might not install devDependencies. I'll update my answer.
